# Im not to sure how to sort three variables while calling two other funtions

Tags: python-3.x

I need help with the `sort3` function. Specifically, how I can use `more_than` and `swap` to sort 3 variables.

```py
# Problem: Check if a is greater than b.
# Example: more_than(27, 53) returns: False
function more_than(a, b): 
    # Inputs: integers a and b
    # Output: True if a > b, False otherwise
    pass
```

```py
# Problem: Swaps a and b, returns (b, a)
# Example: swap(27, 53) returns: 53, 27
function swap(a, b):
    # Inputs: integers a and b 
    # Output: b and a
    pass
```

```py
# Problem: sort a, b and c into order from smallest to largest by calling the functions more_than() and swap() as needed. At most, you may need to swap three times.
# Example: sort(34, 12, 78) returns: 12, 34, 78
function sort3(a, b, c):
    # Inputs: integers a, b, and c
    # Outputs: a, b and c in sorted order
    pass
```

Comment: 'I am not sure' - give it a try. If you encounter issues let us know (by editing the question) and we'll gladly help you through it.

Comment: Im still having issues on what the format will be.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to the problem, but I highly encourage to make your own solution. The best way to learn programming is to practice it. Figure out what you can do and what you can't, experiment. Try doing this using a for loop, or having multiple if statements.

```py
def more_than(a, b):
    return a > b

def swap(a, b):
    return b, a

def sort3(a, b, c):
    print("Start:", a, b, c)

    # if a is greater than b, then we want to swap b with a so that we end up with (b, a)
    if more_than(a, b):
        # a = what b was, b = what a was
        a, b = swap(a, b)
        print(a, b, c)

    # if b is greater than c, then we want to swap c with b so that we end up with (c, b)
    if more_than(b, c):
        b, c = swap(b, c)
        print(a, b, c)

    # if we changed what b is in our last if block, we need to compare a and b again
    if more_than(a, b):
        a, b = swap(a, b)
        print(a, b, c)

    return a, b, c

print(sort3(2, 3, 1))
```